# ¿(2.3 - 1.8) != 0.5 es cierto en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estuve haciendo algunas sentencias en R, y me di con la sorpresa que en R, no reconoce a `(2.3-1.8) == 0.5` como cierto, si no todo lo contrario; esto también sucede con otros comparaciones como `(2.6 - 1.4) ==1.2`.
Si alguien tuvo este mismo percance, espero me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenido Keith Caballero Rodriguez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.. Efectivamente es cierto, y no solo en R, pasa en todos los lenguajes cuando se maneja números de coma flotante.  Revisa el enlace que te han pasado.

Comment: Verifica también esto que acabo de escribir: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200048/cual-es-la-forma-correcta-de-trabajar-con-n%C3%BAmeros-de-coma-flotante/200049#200049