# Extraer un solo dato en R

Tags: r, rstudio, filtro

tengo un problema y es que estoy creando una función en R que me traiga según la "edad" el valor correspondiente según el género "hombre" o "mujer". Por ejemplo, mi tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera poder según mi función que si la persona tiene 20.25 años y sea hombre "l.x" me de solamente el resultado 99911.00, porque con eso debo hacer operaciones de matemáticas.

Espero haber sido claro y puedan ayudarme. LO AGRADEZCO MUCHO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas una función para resolverlo:

```
df$I.x.[df$edad==20.25]
```

Es decir: el valor de `I.x.`  dónde el valor de `edad` sea igual a 20.25. Si lo quisieras encapsular en un función sería algo así:

```
get_ix_for_edad <- function(df, edad) {df$I.x.[df$edad==edad]}
```

Consideraciones adicionales:

- Es conveniente normalizar los nombres de columna, si bien `I.x.` es válido, no estaría mal darle un nombre más sencillo y compatible
- Puedes tener problema con la igualdad en el caso de números de punto flotante, si fuera así revisa [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200048/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-forma-adecuada-para-comparar-n%C3%BAmeros-de-coma-flotante)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado bastante y seguiré tus recomendaciones.