# Error R - referencias a valores o variables en dataframrs

Tags: r, dataframe, calculo, referencias

Tengo este codigo R, que deberia ir tomando los puntos de la tabla en Y_datos segun el punto de X_datos que se indique, dependiendo del punto en X inicial dado (punto_central_index) y de H.

El codigo es simple. El objetivo final es hacer la formula que esta al final del codigo, pero el problema esta en:
**(tabla$y_datos[tabla$x_datos == (punto_central_index - h)])**
Y tambien da problemas el mismo pero con "**+h**"

Da error en el sentido de que me devuelve "**numeric(0)**" dependiendo el valor de punto_central_index que yo elija. Es raro. A veces da error y a veces no.

Este es el codigo entero:

```
x_datos <- c(2.31,   2.91,   3.51,   4.11,   4.71,   5.31,   5.91)
y_datos <- c(3.8915, 2.8249, 1.4308, 0.3549, 0.0994, 0.8591, 2.4595)
tabla <- data.frame(x_datos, y_datos)

punto_central_index = 4.11
h=0.6

index_center <- as.numeric(tabla$y_datos[tabla$x_datos == (punto_central_index)])
index_menos_h <- as.numeric(tabla$y_datos[tabla$x_datos == (punto_central_index - h)])
index_mas_h <- as.numeric(tabla$y_datos[tabla$x_datos == (punto_central_index + h)])

#formula objetivo final:
(index_menos_h - 2 * index_center + index_mas_h) / (h^2)
```

Comment: Bienvenida al mundo de los números de punto flotante, dónde nada es lo que parece. Esto `tabla$x_datos[3] == (punto_central_index - h)` es `FALSE` ¿Cómo? si vemos que los dos son 3.51, pues no, ninguno es exactamente 3.51. Para una representación más completa de cada valor: `sprintf("%.60f", tabla$x_datos[3])` y `sprintf("%.60f", punto_central_index - h)` y así vemos hasta 60 decimales y ahora sí vemos que no son iguales.

Comment: La solución corta es `isTRUE(all.equal(tabla$x_datos[3], (punto_central_index - h)))`, ahora para un explicación más completa te sugiero leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200048/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-forma-adecuada-para-comparar-n%c3%bameros-de-punto-flotante

Comment: Y de paso, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.